# How to avoid exception on disconnect for JDBC driver?

Tags: java, oracle, exception, jdbc, disconnect

I use JDBC connection to Oracle database.
Sometimes when I try disconnect I receive error:

```
Io exception Broken pipe
```

This is because network connection was broken.
How to better handler this exception?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

But you wanted to be disconnected anyway, so where's the problem?

You could either log it with a relatively mild log level, or just swallow the exception entirely (I recommend the former)

Comment: I am afraid that JDBC driver will be in not correct state after this exception. How to be sure that jdbc driver in correct state?

Comment: @user710818 nothing about connecting or disconnecting changes the state of the driver. If you're talking about the connection, the connection will be closed, and you will have to create a new one to reconnect

Comment: I am not sure about isValid method. Can it be used before disconnect?

Comment: @user710818 SIR (or MAAM) - I have answered the original question that you asked. Your question now is (a) a new question and (b) something you could easily test yourself